# Lights show in Cycles but not in Eevee for Windows laptop

Tags: cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, lighting, windows

I recently got a Windows HP laptop and am testing Blender on it. I've found that lights for my files don't appear in Eevee but they do appear in Cycles. Even after increasing the brightness for the lights, they still don't show up in Eevee. Does anyone have this same problem?

Comment: You should give more information what kind of lights you are talking about... a sun, point light, spot light or area light? Or do you mean mesh lights with emissive materials? Because the latter only work in _Cycles_ but not in _Eevee_, so this wouldn't be a problem with your laptop, Windows or Blender, just the normal way as it is.

Comment: As Gordon says we lack informations, please share your file or at least show some screenshots